# More screens with less content or less screens with more content

Tags: usability, interaction-design, client

Well my problem seems very common but i was not able to find any solution or research about it. The problem is i am working on an app that has lot of information to show and also has lot of actions that can be taken on that information. As per Hick's law the less choices per page the less the friction, so i divided the content dividing all the actions to many screens. Which created some flows that go too deep. Which my boss says is not good, having everything in one place is better. So what do you guys think is the best thing to do and how can i prove it to him.

Answer (score 2):

I would guess that the amount of information you referring in one screen would create a cognitive overload. Witch, you should avoid. The more information you put in one place the more effort user has to make to manage the amount of information. Eventually, people give up and drop off. You should minimize the amount of information given. **So your initial approach seems correct**.

Although if you have too many screens that it is not good too. You need to prioritize that information and maybe you would manage to reduce the number of screens?

Anyhow take a look at the article. It will help you have a better discussion with your boss ;)

https://www.nngroup.com/articles/minimize-cognitive-load/